# What are the official XML reserved characters?

Tags: xml, special-characters, reserved

In [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), Microsoft says that XML reserved characters (and their entity) are the following ones:

```
>    &gt;
<    &lt;
&    &amp;
%    &#37;
```

But in [this other page](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx), I found that also `'` is a reserved character (and its entity is `&apos;`).

Can someone indicate me some official reference in which are listed all and only the XML reserved characters?

Comment: Please read for context. The two articles are about different things, and only one is from Microsoft.

Comment: I didn't say that the second is by Microsoft...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax), the only characters that *must* be escaped when used as character content rather than markup are `&` (as `&amp;`, `&#38;` or `&#x26;`) and `<` (as `&lt;`, `&#60;` or `&#x3C;`), plus `>` when it is part of the sequence `]]>`.  In addition, single quotes must be escaped (typically as `&apos;`) in single quoted attribute values, and double quotes (typically as `&quot;`) in double-quoted attribute values, and any character that is not representable in the character encoding used to serialize the document must be escaped as a suitable character reference.

You don't *have* to escape double quotes in single quoted attributes or vice versa, but it won't do any harm if you do so.

Of course, you *may* escape every `>`, `"` and `'` (and any other character) within character content if you want to, without changing the meaning.

Comment: The reason "%" is present in the Microsoft list is probably because "%" is reserved in certain contexts within the DTD.

Answer (score 5):

XML doesn't have any notion of "reserved characters".

It has [predefined entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent) which represent the most of the characters which may (depending on context) have special meaning in an XML document  (`"`, `<`, `>`, `&` `'`).

It doesn't have named entities for the space character or `=` because the places where they have special meaning are places that you can't have data.