# How to ignore html in an xml element when validating with relaxng compact

Tags: relaxng, relaxng-compact

How can I have a pattern that ignores html within an element rather than the validator trying to validate it

```
<stuff>
   <data>
      this is some text <b>with the odd</b> bit of html<p>and unclosed tags
   </data>
</stuff>
```

This isn't valid but I tried things like

```
datatypes xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
start = stuff

stuff = element stuff
{
   element data { * }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't allow arbitrary unmodified HTML within XML. Either escape the individual special characters ([What are the official XML reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758345/what-are-the-official-xml-reserved-characters)) or encapsulate the HTML within a CDATA container ([Is it possible to insert HTML content in XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document)).

Comment: Not my data, it is from an external source so escaping it isn't possible.

Comment: Well, it's easy for any XML parser to trip over the HTML. I guess you could sanitize it on import with e.g. a regular expression-based find-and-replace before feeding the file to the XML parser.

Comment: so far so good - the html is good and I've added the few tags that are used to the rnc - not ideal - but it is working.

Comment: That still wouldn't work with unclosed tags, though, right? (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags for a full list)

Comment: No it won't so far in 15K LOC of xml I've gone through the html is well formed. I expect though somewhere it is not - seems to me odd that I cannot absorb the value of an element 'as-is'

Comment: Well, XML is just much more strict than HTML.

Comment: And again, the CDATA sections are specifically meant to allow you to store things like raw HTML. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to validate an XML document with non-well-formed HTML in it, since on account of the non-wellformedness such documents are not XML documents.  But if in fact the input you're getting is XML, then you can certainly define `data` to allow any well-formed HTML elements, or any well-formed XML.

Allowing any well-formed XML is the simplest.  We define a pattern than means "any well-formed XML here":  any elements encountered are validated using the same pattern, recursively:

```
wellformed-xml = (text
                 | element * { wellformed-xml }
                 )*
```

Now define the `data` element to use that pattern:

```
stuff = element stuff {
            element data { wellformed-xml }
        }
```

If you really want to ensure that it's just HTML, you'll want a nameclass more restrictive than "*".  I've populated it with `b`, `i`, `p`, `span`, and `div`, and leave it as an exercise to you to add the other elements you want.

```
start = stuff
stuff =
  element stuff {
    element data { wellformed-html }
  }

wellformed-html =
  (text
   | element b | div | i | p | span { wellformed-html }
   )*
```

If you want to be able to support XHTML input as well, you'll want to use a namespace reference; again, an exercise for the reader.