# C# Quickbooks Desktop Integration issue

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, quickbooks

We use the QB .NET SDK to integrate to QB Desktop. We've been doing this for years with a lot of success but are running into an issue when we are now trying to do an ItemReceipt transaction with serial numbers (We've not done serial numbers with QB before). We are receiving an:

2022/11/07 09:38:39>!QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
at Interop.QBFC13.QBSessionManagerClass.DoRequests(IMsgSetRequest request)
at DCCQBFuncs.DCCQB.send_message_to_qb() in DCCQB.cs:line 413
QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor.2

That's all we get and we're not sure how to troubleshoot this since it doesn't look like we have access to the XML text stream in the SDK???

As a note ... when we take out the serial number ... all works well and yes this is QB Enterprise (Only edition that allows serial numbers) and serialization is enabled.

Line Item Code:

```
                //SCROLL THROUGH ALL ITEMS
            for (c = 0; c < part_numbers.Length; c++)
            {
                //CREATE A NEW LINE ITEM
                IORItemLineAdd lineitem = itemReceiptAddrq.ORItemLineAddList.Append();
                
                //SET ITEM CODE
                lineitem.ItemLineAdd.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue(part_numbers[c]);

                //IF WE HAVE SERIAL NUMBERS IN DATA THEN ADD HERE
                if (serial_numbers != null && serial_numbers.Length == part_numbers.Length)
                {
                    lineitem.ItemLineAdd.ORSerialLotNumber.SerialNumber.SetValue(serial_numbers[c]);
                }
                
                //ADD QUANTITY (REQUIRED)
                lineitem.ItemLineAdd.Quantity.SetValue(Double.Parse(quantities[c]));
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Marshall

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
<ItemReceiptAddRq requestID = "0">
<ItemReceiptAdd>
<VendorRef>
<FullName>GPCTX</FullName>
</VendorRef>
<TxnDate>2022-11-08</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>NA</RefNumber>
<Memo>Receive from DCC IdyllicWMS Mobile Scanner</Memo>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004441</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004442</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004443</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004444</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004445</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004446</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004447</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004448</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004449</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004450</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004451</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004452</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004453</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004454</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004455</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004456</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004457</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004458</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004459</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004460</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004461</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004462</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004463</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004464</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004465</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004466</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004467</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004468</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004469</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004470</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004471</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004472</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004473</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004474</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004475</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004476</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004477</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004478</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004479</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004480</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004481</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004482</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004483</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004484</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004485</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004486</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004487</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004488</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004489</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
<ItemLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>GPSB100</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<SerialNumber>0004490</SerialNumber>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</ItemLineAdd>
</ItemReceiptAdd>
</ItemReceiptAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The above is the QB msgreq object toXML()

Thanks again

Comment: _it doesn't look like we have access to the XML text stream in the SDK...when we take out the serial number ... all works well_: I'm just guessing here, but I'd say that the issue is with the serial number. Perhaps you can add one (or two) to your post. Also, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. If applicable, adding images to your post may also be beneficial.

Comment: Certainly a good idea!

Comment: I still don't see a sample serial number in the post. Certain characters aren't allowed in the data. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758475/10024425) for more info.

Comment: Looks like the documentation is here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/itemreceiptadd (clicking on C# shows some code). In the sample code, it looks like an expiration date is also set: `.ItemLineAdd.ExpirationDateForSerialLotNumber.SetValue("2022-09-29");`

Comment: Yea. Serial number expiration dates were not supported in QBSDK13 so I upgraded to QBSDK16,added expiration date and got the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chatted with Intuit on this and we were using the wrong version of QBXML to utilize serialization (Advanced Inventory). We need to move from QMXML13 to QBXML16.

So in your code switch from top line to the bottom:

```
//IMsgSetRequest imsr = qbs.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);

IMsgSetRequest imsr = qbs.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 16, 0);
```